# How to get more detailed changes after executing hg update?

Tags: mercurial

I have executed `hg update -C` and I got the minimal message `x files update, y files removed` etc..
How can I get more verbose information about which files were affected after executing the update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what changeset you had checked out before you updated you can do `hg diff -r THAT_REVISION` and see a diff or a stat depending on other options.

*After* you've done the update you're sunk if you don't know what you'd checked out previously .  If that's happening a lot of you you could add a `pre-update` hook that echoes the current revision id before updating.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `-v` will give you more information - it lists all the files that were changed.

Oddly, `hg help update` doesn't mention anything about the `-v` flag but it does work.

Comment: I am aware of the -v parameter but I forgot to add it when I executed the command. So can I somehow have the same output after update?

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I missed that bit of the question.

Comment: You missed it because it wasn't mentioned.. :)